# How to define a string in python with double and single quotes

Tags: python

I am using python to communicate with the OS.

I need to create a string of the following form:

```
string = "done('1') && done('2')"
```

Note that my string MUST have the double quotes in it, but I am not sure how to do that since the double quotes are used in python for defining a string.

Then I do something like:

```
os.system(string)
```

But the system would only read the string with the double and single quotes in it.

I tried:

```
>>> s = '"done('1') && done('2')"'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s = '"done('1') && done('2')"'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried the triple quotes suggested here but i get an error:

```
>>> s = """"done('1') && done('2')""""
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    s = """"done('1') && done('2')""""
                                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: See also the [relevant section of the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) or the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a [triply quoted string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) you need to remember that the string *ends* when Python finds a closing set of three quotes - and it is not greedy about it.  So you can:

Change to wrapping in triple *single* quotes:

```
my_command = '''"done('1') && done('2')"'''
```

Escape the ending quote:

```
my_command = """"done('1') && done('2')\""""
```

or add space around your quotes and call `strip` on the resulting string:

```
my_command = """
"done('1') && done('2')"
""".strip()
# Blank lines are for illustrative purposes only
# You can do it all on one line as well (but then it looks like you have
# 4 quotes (which can be confusing)
```

Comment: this works, but i see it in python like this: >>> my_command
'"done(\'1\') && done(\'2\')"' (it adds the \, is that ok when i pass it to os.system??  thanks!!!!

Comment: @Dnaiel - yes, it is - Python is just using an alternate representation of the same string.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape both kinds of quotes:

```
s = '"done(\'1\') && done(\'2\')"'
```

Answer (score 2):

All four flavors of quotes:

```
print('''"done('1') && done('2')"''')  # No escaping required here.
print(""""done('1') && done('2')\"""")
print("\"done('1') && done('2')\"")
print('"done(\'1\') && done(\'2\')"')
```

Output:

```
"done('1') && done('2')"
"done('1') && done('2')"
"done('1') && done('2')"
"done('1') && done('2')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting:
string = "\"done('1') && done('2')\""

Ignore if this does not answer your question.